# How to make git conflicted files ordered in desired way for solving

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-config, meld, mergetool

How can I make my conflicted files to come in desired order to resolve conflicts.
e.g if I have 2 branches named foo and bar
i want to merge foo into bar and git gives me conflicts as below

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in x.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in z.py
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in y.py
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

here three files are conflicted, (x.py, y.py, z.py)
if i use command

```
git mergetool --tool=meld
```

meld tool will open a file always in alphabetical order ( here x, y then z)
but i want to resolve conflict in the  y, z, x order.

Please let me know if anyone knows the solution or workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always pass the file names manually:

```
git mergetool --tool=meld y.py
git mergetool --tool=meld z.py
git mergetool --tool=meld x.py
```